# Save image twice different sizes with php

Tags: php

I have a image cropper that first crops the image and then saves it to my server, now i need to save the cropped image twice the first image is size that is set in the cropper (260 x 260) and the second saved image should be 115 x 260. this is the script i use atm to save it:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
ini_set("gd.jpeg_ignore_warning", 1);
ini_set("memory_limit", "100M");
$src = $_POST['url'];
$targ_w = $_POST['setW'];
$targ_h = $_POST['setH'];
$img_r = @imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
$dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_w, $targ_h );

imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$_POST['x'],$_POST['y'],
$targ_w,$targ_h,$_POST['w'],$_POST['h']);

imagejpeg($dst_r, $src, 90);
exit;
```

this makes the image save as 260 x 260 but now it needs to save another image at the same time but with a different size and name, what do i add to this script to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call another imagecopyresampled with new output size and save it

Comment: how do i get it to save with a difrent name?

Comment: `imagejpeg($dst_r, 'differentName.jpg', 90);` (just use new resource)

Comment: @Holapress: imagecopyresampled crops a region from an image and copies it on another image, stretched  to set output size, imagejpeg save an image as jpeg. So combining those 2 functions you can do whatever you need.